# javamail cannot read multipart/mixed mails

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am unable to retrieve the content of the body of **"multipart/MIXED"** mails ...

This is what I use to reading mails ....

```
private String read(Message message) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        String result = message.getContentType().toString() + " Unable to read";
        if (message instanceof MimeMessage) {
            MimeMessage m = (MimeMessage) message;
            Object contentObject = m.getContent();
            if (contentObject instanceof Multipart) {
                BodyPart clearTextPart = null;
                BodyPart htmlTextPart = null;
                Multipart content = (Multipart) contentObject;
                int count = content.getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    BodyPart part = content.getBodyPart(i);
                    if (part.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                        clearTextPart = part;
                        break;
                    } else if (part.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                        htmlTextPart = part;
                    }
                }
                if (clearTextPart != null) {
                    result = (String) "<html><body>"
                            + clearTextPart.getContent() + "</body></html>";
                } else if (htmlTextPart != null) {
                    String html = (String) htmlTextPart.getContent();
                    result = android.text.Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
                }
            } else if (contentObject instanceof String) {
                String html = (String) contentObject;
                result = html;
            } else {
                result = "not found";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

As you can see the problem is , the mail wont even pass the condition **(message instanceof MimeMessage)** ...

The output for "multipart/MIXED" mail is :

```
multipart/MIXED; boundary=20cf306..... Unable to read
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String processBody( > Part p < , String operacao)    
 } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
                *** MimeMessage m = (MimeMessage) p; ***
                Multipart mp = (Multipart) m.getContent();
                for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                    t = processBody(mp.getBodyPart(i), operacao);
                    if (t != null)
                        return t;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough detail.  Certainly you can trace the flow of your program through that code.  What exactly is happening?  If it's failing one of the tests, what are the actual values you're seeing and what do you expect?

What version of JavaMail are you using?

Are you reading the message from a mail server?  What does the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: Hi, I am using JavaMail **1.4.7** ... also i can see anything wrong in debug ... what is happening is what i described above ... i am able to read all mails except mails that content type is **multipart/MIXED** ... they are not even instanceof MimeMessage ...

Comment: If you don't provide more details, I can't help you.

Comment: Its ok, thank for you  interest ... the problem was that i was not able to proces mails that has a multipart in multipart ... **msgshow** helped a lot ....

Comment: i will post the solution later :)